# UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight NOT working inside DetailViewController.m with iOS 5.1

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer, ios5.1

this is my first question, but i use this site a lot this last months (thanks for all).

My problem: i have a split-view project for i-Pad. In the DetailViewController I use a UIButton.
Here's some code from *DetailViewController.h:*

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;
- (void)swipeRightDetected:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
```

In *DetailViewController.m* I just do this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightDetected:)];
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.button addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
}

- (void)swipeRightDetected:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    if (recognizer.view == self.button) {
    NSLog(@"YEAH");
    }
}
```

Now the problem is: it was working perfectly with iOS 5.0.1 and previous. Now it doesn't work any longer. IT WORKS FOR ANY OTHER DIRECTION but NOT for RIGHT direction and only in a DetailViewController!!
It only works if you hit the iPad with strength and speed (like a slap!), and same thing for the simulator.. it only works if you do the swipe very very very fast!

I think it's a bug.. what should i do? Maybe post the same question on apple forum?
Thank you all, you're all great!!
Marco

Comment: Are you linking this in Interface?

Comment: yes.. it is linked properly... it works 1 time every 5/6 times...!! in any other direction it works good as always!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would guess that this has to do with the new "sliding presentation style" of the split view controller in iOS 5.1. The [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-5_1/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011329) say that you can disable this behavior by setting `presentsWithGesture` to `NO`.

Another option might be to implement `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` in your gesture recognizer's delegate.

Comment: thx thx thx!! I didn't got what they mean in the release notes!! Now i got it!! thx again!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm blatantly copying this answer from a fantastic tip on this StackOverflow page:
[Master Table Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628107/master-table-application)

In your **AppDelegate.m** file, add this line at the end of your "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" function:

```
splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = false;
```

Suddenly, right-swiping works again on Master-Detail pages.

(Relieved sigh.)