# Popover master of a Master Detail project ... how to keep it from displaying?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, master-detail

I am using the Master of a Master detail project as a popover, however in one circumstance where I add a subview to the detail view I don't want the user to be able to slide out the masterview popover , is there anyway to hide or temporary disable the popover ?

Answer (score 0):

you can check if your popover is visible and dismiss it when you recceive a notification that the popover will be shown:

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc
         popoverController:(UIPopoverController*)pc 
 willPresentViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController{
  if ([pc isPopoverVisible]) {
     [pc dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
  }
}
```

Starting iOS5 if you implement the splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation method in your delegate controller (usually the detail view controller) you can prevent the master controller to be shown on a popover:

```
- (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
   shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
              inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
  return NO;
}
```

I believe the last solution is more what you are looking at.

Comment: Hmm, the event fires fine but I can't seem to dismiss the popover, can you dismiss it on a willappear event ? the condition of isPopoverVisible never gets met.

Comment: no that's a bad idea. The splitviewcontroller is responsible to dismiss its childview controller. As i said the second solution might be more appropriate to u

Comment: those get fired upon loading however it is only during a series of events after loading that I want to block the popup. I think you are getting me closer though

Comment: those methods are really your only two points of control for the display of the masterview controller in a popover. I don't see what kind of other events you would like to catch here.

Comment: depending on a situation in my app I want to disable the popover, the events above let me know the view is about to appear but i can't seem to stop it from appearing.

Comment: did u check if  [pc dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]; is called?

Comment: yes it does run the [pc dismissPopoverAnimated:YES] but doesn't remove the popover

Comment: i think u need a better understanding of what u are doin at this point. Did u read this at least? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009277

Comment: i have play a bit with the default template. Actually the popover is never shown by default except if you click on the master button...

Comment: this was able to solve my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628107/master-table-application

Comment: ok i didn't know u can slide the popover when  in portrait mode. I just thought you need to press the top left button.