# Adding swipe gesture recognizer to DetailViewContoller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have simple xcode project just made from "Master-Detail Application" template, for iPad. When device is in Portrait orientation, master view is hidden and when you swipe right on detail view, master view will show up. Now, i want to add right swipe gesture recognizer to detail view, like that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandler)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

-(void)swipeHandler{
    NSLog(@"SWIPE");
}
```

But this code causes that when i swipe on detail view, "SWIPE" log appears in console, but master view doesn't show up.

How to add right swipe gesture recognizer to detail view, so it wont prevent master view to show up and my handler for recognizer will work?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT. I want my right swipe recognizer handler to work simultaneously with this built in one, which shows up master view, but that following code isn't a solution for this specific situation:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 38):

you should set the direction for the swipe in order to add the right swipe

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandler:)];
    [gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

and your swipe handler might look like

```
-(void)swipeHandler:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Swipe received.");
}
```

Comment: I think right swipe is actually default direction and this is not what  the question is about

Comment: Yes, i did. My recognizer works perfectlly but this built in one doesn't work any more and thats the problem.

Comment: are you setting the delegate properly? for the `gestureRecognizer`? as you are implementing the delegate method

Comment: Yes, i have checked that, but still i get only my gesture recognizer to work and master vew doesn't show up.

Comment: try this property might be this does the trick... `self.splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = YES; //for showing the maset view`

Comment: [check this out might be helpful for your particular propblem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628107/master-table-application)

Comment: Thanks. But this not what i am looking for. I need solution, when my recognizer works and master view still shows up when i swipe. So this is situation when to handlers to the same recognizer works simultaneously.

Comment: [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];  // not gestureRecognizer

Answer (score 18):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRecognizer:)];
    recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

- (void)swipeRecognizer:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            CGPoint Position = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + 100.0, self.view.frame.origin.y);
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(Position.x , Position.y , self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try This

//Right Swipe

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandlerRight:)];
[gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

//Left Swipe

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandlerLeft:)];
[gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

call method

```
-(void)swipeHandlerRight:(id)sender
{
    //Your ViewController
}

-(void)swipeHandlerLeft:(id)sender
{
 //Your ViewController
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works. It pushes the view controller from the navigationController.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer           alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(swipeHandler:)];
     [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

-(IBAction)swipeHandler:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
      NSLog(@"SWIPE");
      UIViewController *tb = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
      tb = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController: tb animated:YES];
}
```

Then be sure to go to storyboard (or you could also do this manually) - click on the Detail View Controller and give the View controller the Identity: DetailViewController

Comment: I am not sure what to do with your answer.. Does knowledge about swipe direction give me solution to my problem?

Comment: i really need that both: my and built in regonizers to work on the same view, which is detail view.

Comment: do you want to do your own swipe handling and disable the presentation of the master view or do you want to react on the master view being presented?

Comment: @MartinUllrich I want to do my own swipe handling, but i dont want stop master view to present. Problem is that, when i add my own swipe handling somehow it stop presenting master view

Comment: @darko_5 did you try out my idea above? I edited my original post after I found a solution trying it out on xcode. did it work for you? Did you find another solution?

Comment: @user1066524 I have tried and it is interesting piece of code. But master view need to show up not detail. When you swipe on detail view in portrait mode master view will show up in default, i need it to still show evan i add my own swipe handler.

Answer (score 0):

swift 4.0

Step 1: Add swipe Gesture(s) in viewDidLoad() method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
    swipeLeft.direction = .left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = .right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)


}
```

Step 2: Check the gesture detection in handleGesture() method

```
@objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right {
        print("Swipe Right")
    }
    else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left {
        print("Swipe Left")
    }

}
```